# Why can't I print the String out of my multidimensional-Array?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I've read in other posts, that instead of writing just `System.out.println(finalPressedKey);`
 you should write `System.out.println(Arrays.toString((finalPressedKey));` because otherwise it will just return the location where the String is saved (as far as I understood it).

```
public static String PressedKey[] = new String[2000];

public static String[][] finalPressedKey = {{ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }}; // 12

public static String FPK3;

public static void upcounter(KeyEvent e) {

    for (int x = 0; x < PressedKey.length; x++) {

        if (PressedKey[x] != null && PressedKey[x + counter] != null) {

        //FPK counter is supposed to be a line, and counter is where the words are supposed to be saved

        finalPressedKey[FPKcounter][counter] =
        finalPressedKey[FPKcounter] + PressedKey[x + counter];

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalPressedKey));
        }

    }
```

Whenever I Press a Button, it should be saved in my `PressedKey` Array, and finalPressedKey is supposed to contain itself, and `PressedKey` (also , only the last element of the array is supposed to be printed), but instead it just prints `[[Ljava.lang.String;@76f42c4b]`

I also tried using `Arrays.deepToString();` but it gives me the same output as with `Arrays.toString();`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If think if you used `Arrays.deepToString()` it would work. How about you post your attempt with that?

Comment: *otherwise it will just return the location where the String is saved*--this is printed  object internal hash code, which is in no way related to "location"

Answer (score 2):

A `String[][]` is not a 2-d array. It is an array of `String[]`. The difference is subtle but important.

The method `Arrays.toString()` takes an array, iterates through its elements, calls `toString()` on all of them, and adds a prefix, suffix, and delimiters. Since you give it a `String[][]` (an array of `String[]`), it will do the following:

- Iterate through the elements (each of them a `String[]`)
- call `toString()` on each element - giving the default `toString()` value of an array - i.e. its memory address (not really but for this purpose it doesn't matter)
- concatenate

Luckily for you, there is an easier way - just use `Arrays.deepToString()`. This behaves as you would expect.

Comment: OP already "tried using `Arrays.deepToString();`" I bet the string representation is already inside the arrays

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the whole code, but following statement is very suspicious:

```
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter][counter] =
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter] + PressedKey[x + counter];
```

since it is adding an array (`finalPressedKey[...]`) to a string (`PressedKey[...]`), which will result in that *strange* text - the standard textual representation of an array (returned by `toString`). (from a *mathematical point of view*, it's strange to have 2 indexes )2D_ before the assignment and only one on the right side (1D) for same matrix)

I'm not sure, since we cannot see what `counter`is, but I believe you wanted something like:

```
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter][counter] =
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter][counter] + PressedKey[x + counter];
```

that is, an additional `[counter]` on second line.

This can also be written as

```
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter][counter] += PressedKey[x + counter];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the elements of your array with

```java
for(int i = 0; i<finalPressedKey[0].length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<finalPressedKey[1].length; j++){
      System.out.println(finalPressedKey[i][j]);
   } 
}
```

if I understand it correctly.

Comment: If you fix the indentation of the code the OP could understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store lines of strings, a normal String[] is good for you

```
finalPressedKey[FPKcounter] += PressedKey[x + counter];
```

even though I wouldn't recomment doing this, no matter what you're trying to accomplish, since this will create a new String object each time a key is pressed.

Maybe ask the question differently and tell us what you're trying to do. I guess String arrays might not be the way to go.